# class_eval vs instance_eval

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, instance-eval, class-eval

Is there any difference in how `class_eval` & `instance_eval` work except `def`? Inside `class_eval` block `def` defines method to class itself (i.e. instance method) and inside `instance_eval` `def` defines method to the eigenclass of the class (i.e. class method). AFAIK all other features work identically in both cases (e.g. `define_method`, `attr_accessor`, `class << self; end`, defining constants). Is it true?

**Answer is**: `def`, `undef` and `alias` have different contexts for `class_eval` and `instance_eval`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Long story short:

- `Object.instance_eval &block` sets:

  - `self` to `Object`
  - The "current class" to [`Object.singleton_class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class)
- `Object.class_eval &block` sets:

  - `self` to `Object`
  - The "current class" to `Object`

The "current class" is used for `def`, `undef` and `alias`, as well as constant and class variable lookups.

---

Now, let's have a look at the implementation details.

Here's how [`module_eval`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/vm_eval.c#L1402) and [`instance_eval`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/vm_eval.c#L1331) are implemented in C:

```
VALUE rb_mod_module_eval(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE mod) {
    return specific_eval(argc, argv, mod, mod);
}

VALUE rb_obj_instance_eval(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self) {
    VALUE klass;
    if (SPECIAL_CONST_P(self)) { klass = Qnil; }
    else { klass = rb_singleton_class(self); }
    return specific_eval(argc, argv, klass, self);
}
```

Both call [`specific_eval`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/vm_eval.c#L1281), which takes the following arguments: `int argc`, `VALUE *argv`, `VALUE klass` and `VALUE self`.

Note that:

- `module_eval` passes the `Module` or `Class` instance as both `klass` *and* `self`
- `instance_eval` passes the object's *singleton class* as `klass`

If given a block, `specific_eval` will call [`yield_under`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/vm_eval.c#L1242), which takes the following arguments: `VALUE under`, `VALUE self` and `VALUE values`.

```
if (rb_block_given_p()) {
    rb_check_arity(argc, 0, 0);
    return yield_under(klass, self, Qundef);
}
```

There are two important lines in `yield_under`:

1. `block.self = self;`

   This sets the `self` of the block to the receiver.
2. `cref = vm_cref_push(th, under, NOEX_PUBLIC, blockptr);`

   The [`cref`](http://ruby2cext.rubyforge.org/limitations.html#section7) is a *linked list*
   which specifies the "current class", which is used for `def`, `undef` and `alias`, as well
   as constant and class variable lookups.

   That line basically sets the `cref` to `under`.

   Finally:

   - When called from `module_eval`, `under` will be the `Class` or `Module`
     instance.
   - When called from `instance_eval`, `under` will be the *singleton class* of
     `self`.

Comment: There is one thing: inside `class_eval` assigning constants and class variables does not work the way it works in class definition/reopening: it uses outer scope.

Comment: @Alexey, you are right. I bet it has something to do with that `NODE_FL_CREF_PUSHED_BY_EVAL` constant. Many methods, like [`Module::nesting`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-c-nesting) for example, seem to ignore a `cref` node if the flag is set.

Comment: Shouldn't the first version be `Object.class_eval &block`? Otherwise you're not showing the different between `instance_eval` on the class and `class_eval` on the class, you're showing the difference between `instance eval` on an instance of the class and `class_eval` on the class.

Comment: @MichaelHewson, I used a class for `class_eval` because the method is only defined for `Module` instances. Classes are objects so `instance_eval` behaves similarly even if `object = Object`. The `self` will be `Object` but methods defined in the block will become class methods of `Object` because they were actually defined on `Object.singleton_class`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to say that the _second_ version, the one using `instance_eval`, should also use `Object` instead of `Object.new` so that both are being called on the `Object` class. I just think having the same method receiver would illustrate the difference between the methods better.

Comment: Oh no, that's not right either :facepalm: it's the first version that I'm talking about, the one with `instance_eval`. What I said about having the same method receiver still applies though. (Sorry for all the comments, wish I could have gotten it right the first time.)

Comment: @Michael, I see what you mean now and I agree. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

`instance_eval` lets you access the instance's instance variables directly, and use `self` as a reference to the instance.

Comment: `class_eval` and `instance_eval` work identically in that respect