# Customizing a Ruby Struct with pre-defined definitions and a custom block

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Given the following program, in which I want to:

1. Create a `Struct` with some keys
2. Provide some default customization
3. Allow a block to be passed for further customization

```
module Magic
    def self.MagicStruct(keys_array, &block)
        Struct.new(*keys_array) do
            @keys = keys_array
            def self.magic_class_method
                puts "constructed with #{@keys}"
            end

            def magic_instance_method
                puts "instance method"
            end

            # --- DOESN'T WORK, CONTEXT IS OUTSIDE OF MODULE --- #
            # yield if block_given?

            instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
        end
    end
end

Foo = Magic.MagicStruct([:a, :b, :c]) do
    puts "class customizations executing..."

    def self.custom_class_method
        puts "custom class method"
    end

    def custom_instance_method
        puts "custom instance method"
    end
end

Foo.magic_class_method  # works
Foo.custom_class_method # works

x = Foo.new({a: 10, b: 20, c: 30})
x.magic_instance_method  # works
x.custom_instance_method # fails
```

Output:

```
class customizations executing...
constructed with [:a, :b, :c]
custom class method
instance method
Traceback (most recent call last):
`<main>': undefined method `custom_instance_method' for #<struct Foo a={:a=>10, :b=>20, :c=>30}, b=nil, c=nil> (NoMethodError)
```

Why is the `self.custom_class_method` correctly added to the `Foo` class, but the `custom_instance_method` is not? This usage is clearly stated in [the Struct documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Struct.html), so I'm afraid there's some kind of scoping or context issue I'm missing here.

I would prefer to keep the nice `def method() ... end` syntax rather than resorting to having a strict requirement to use `define_method("method")` in the customization block, which does happen to work.

Comment: Try replacing `instance_eval` with `class_eval` and it should work. "Instance" in this method name means not what you're going to define (instance method in your case) but rather a context in which the particular piece of code will be evaluated. Just evaluate your block in the class context (like a "normal" method definition would be defined)...

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov that worked! Happy to accept it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Note that Ruby 3.1.0 allows you to define a Struct with keywords when [Struct#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Struct.html#method-c-new) is passed `keyword_init: true`. This may simplify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby there is the notion of a *current class* which is the target of keywords such as `def`.

When you use `instance_eval`, the current class is set to `self.singleton_class`. In other words, `def x` and `def self.x` are equivalent. In your code, `custom_instance_method` is defined on the singleton class of the newly created `Struct`, making it a class method.

When you use `class_eval`, the current class is set to `self`. Since this method is only available on classes, it will set the current class to the one you called the method on. In other words, `def x` will define a method that's available to all objects of that class. This is what you wanted.

For more details, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10306049/512904).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://rubygems.org/gems/immutable_struct_ex) is a gem I wrote that I believe does most, if not all that you want (not so sure about adding class methods though, I'd have to play with that). While the `Struct` created is *immutable*, you can have a look at the code and alter it to meet your needs; it's pretty simple. What you'd be interested in, would be [here](https://github.com/gangelo/immutable_struct_ex/blob/main/lib/immutable_struct_ex.rb), which basically amounts to what you see below. The extension of the modules uses `instance_eval` in a way that I believe is what you want as well:

```rb
# https://github.com/gangelo/immutable_struct_ex/blob/main/lib/immutable_struct_ex.rb
# Defines the methods used to create/manage the ImmutableStructEx struct.
module ImmutableStructEx
  class << self
    # Most likely changing this method name to #create in subsequent version, but alas...
    def new(**hash, &block)
      Struct.new(*hash.keys, keyword_init: true, &block).tap do |struct|
        return struct.new(**hash).tap do |struct_object|
          struct_object.extend Comparable
          struct_object.extend Immutable
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage details can be found in the [README.md in the github repository](https://github.com/gangelo/immutable_struct_ex).

I hope this help, at least in part.